# how to graph using geom_area?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

Does anyone know why my data is not graphing?

data_frame

```
univ_apps
----------------------------
timeappreceived chr May_12_2002, March_4_2002
bs_ms_phd factor  1 for bs 2 for ms 3 for phd
appid  int   rn89 qw23 et43 

sample data
--------------
timeappreceived   bs_ms_phd   appid

Sept_2_1989          1          rn89
Sept_2_1989          2          dq11
Oct_1_2011           1          bg32
```

etc

```
univdata = ggplot(univ_apps, 
   aes(x= yearappreceived, y= appid, fill=as.factor(bs_ms_phd))) +      
geom_area(position="stack")
```

Am I missing something from the command to graph?

Comment: Here you store the plot to a variable. To print the plot you need to print the contents of the variable. Just type the name of the variable to implicitly print it, or call `print(univdata)`

Comment: Also that version of `univ_apps` looks kind of bizarre. Can you post output of `dput(univ_apps)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data frame as you shown, the "timeappreceived" is chr. I guess the data type of "yearappreceived" is the same as "timeappreceived". You should convert it to numeric. Try the following code.

```
univdata = ggplot(univ_apps, aes(x= as.integer(yearappreceived),
        y= appid, fill=as.factor(bs_ms_phd))) + geom_area(position="stack"); univdata
```

By the way, if the appid is not numeric, you shoud convert them too. But the appid is integer, isn't it?

Comment: thx everyone for your responses,  it was the conversion. <bangs head>